# A question about the weak convergence of curvature measure

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Suppose we have a family of convex bodies with support functions $h_{\epsilon}$. $h_{\epsilon}$ uniformly converges to $h$, which is the suport function of a limiting convex body. $h_{\epsilon}$ is always positve, but $h$ might be $0$ somewhere.
Assume $det(h_{\epsilon ij}+h_{\epsilon}\delta_{ij})=\frac{1}{K_{\epsilon}}$ on $S^{n}$ in generalized sense(namely left hand side as a measure, such that its value on a set equals to the area of inverse image of the gauss map of this set) , where $K_{\epsilon}$ is a positive function. 
Now assume $K_{\epsilon}dx$ as measures on $S^{n}$ weakly converges to $Kdx$, for some function $K\geq0$.
Does it imply $det(h_{ij}+h\delta_{ij})=\frac{1}{K}$ on $S^{n}$ in generalized sense?

Comment: Could you give a definition for support functions?  (As in, is it the characteristic function of the set, or $0 \in C$, $+\infty \notin C$).  

Comment: I believe the OP means the support height function that is usual in convex geometry. Namely, the support function of a set $Q\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ in the direction $\mathbf{u}\in S^{n-1}$ is $\max_{\mathbf{x}\in Q}\langle\mathbf{u},\mathbf{x}\rangle$.